# How can I create dynamic filtering in Vue from a graphql dataset?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, graphql

How do I create a dynamical filter using a computed property from vue when the dataset is from a graphql-query?

I've looked at several articles that all use the array.filter()-method, but I can't get it to work on my dataset (dummy data below):

```
books: [{
                node: {
                title:  'Elon Musk',
                by:'Ashlee Vance',
                },
                node: {
                title:  'Steve Jobs',
                by:'George Llian',
                },
                node: {
                title:  'Face of Facebook',
                by:  'Sandip Paul',
                },
                node: {
                title:  'Tim Cook',
                by:'Andy Atkins',
                url:'http://www.voidcanvas.com/'
                },
                node: {
                title:  'Abdul Kalam',
                by:'Arun Tiwari',
                },
                node: {
                title:  'Story of Elon Musk',
                by:'BP John',
                },
                node: {
                title:  'Story of Bill Gates',
                by:'Russel Crook',
                },
                node: {
                title:  'Becoming Steve Jobs',
                by:'Andrew Russel',
                }
            }]
```

Method:

```
computed: {
        filteredBooks:  function () {
            var  books_array  =  this.books,
            searchString  =  this.searchString;
            if(!searchString) {
                return  books_array;
            }
            searchString  =  searchString.trim().toLowerCase();
            books_array  =  books_array.filter(function(item) {
                if(item.node.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !==  -1) {
                return  item;
                }
            });
            return  books_array;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="search" />

    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li v-for="book in filteredBooks">
        <p>{{book.title}} -by- {{book.by}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my first coding project since early 2000, so please feel free to point me in the right direction if this is the wrong forum for this question.

I set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n8yeqmz/) to play with the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code with some modifications:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    searchString: '',
    books: [{
        title: 'Elon Musk',
        by: 'Ashlee Vance'
      },
      {
        title: 'Steve Jobs',
        by: 'George Llian'
      },
      {
        title: 'Face of Facebook',
        by: 'Sandip Paul'
      },
      {
        title: 'Tim Cook',
        by: 'Andy Atkins',
        url: 'http://www.voidcanvas.com/'
      },
      {
        title: 'Abdul Kalam',
        by: 'Arun Tiwari'
      },
      {
        title: 'Story of Elon Musk',
        by: 'BP John'
      },
      {
        title: 'Story of Bill Gates',
        by: 'Russel Crook'
      },
      {
        title: 'Becoming Steve Jobs',
        by: 'Andrew Russel'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredBooks: function() {
      return this.books.filter(e => this.searchString === '' ? false : e.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ? true : false);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #dbd8d8;
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.design {}

p {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background: #FC756F;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="search" />

  <ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li v-for="book in filteredBooks">
      <p>{{book.title}} -by- {{book.by}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

1. Remove the **node:** from before the objects in the **books** data array - **books** array should contain a bunch of plain objects. If you put **node:** before each object, then you "say" that the every **node** is the key of key-value pair of an object (so the keynames will be identical - **node**!!!)
2. Simplify **filteredBooks** computed - no need to store all the variables. This function (filteredBooks) doesn't change the inputs, so you can use **this** here. The `filter()` functions doesn't change the array it filters - rather it returns a **new array**, containing only values that the iteratee function "saw" as true
3. You check for `!searchString` and that's never the case - **searchString** is always going to be **true** as you initialize it with `searchString: ''` (an empty value - but a value), so I changed it checking for the empty value in the **filteredBooks** computed.
4. I modified the code so that it compares lowercase to lowercase. With your code if someone typed a search string in uppercase, then there'd have been no match.

Comment: Thanks! That's clean and understandable.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :)